# How to provide input to keras for multiple data features?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I know this is really basic question but since I am new to keras I am not able to find the right way to provide input of the dataset mentioned below to keras model.

```
Subject, message, origin_date, is_logged_in, use_cate
```

and a target variable which has total 41 classes.

Subject, Message and Targe variable has string values and remaining columns has numeric values. I dont know how can I pipe this dataset to a simple CNN model?

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess simple ANN works for you case, any reasons for going to CNN. BTW you can give the multiple inputs to Keras as shown here https://github.com/naveenkambham/MachineLearningModels/blob/master/NeuralNetwork.py this is a ANN that accpets 5 features as input features and 2 output features. Please refer this and build the model. Lemme know if you need any clarifications. Please mark this as answer or vote if you find it helpful.